# How to define a list of emails for the job notification plugin in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, plugins, notifications, environment-variables

This is for the Notification Plugin ([link here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin)) for Jenkins.

I have a bunch of Jenkins jobs that I want to keep an eye on.  I want to be alerted/emailed when any changes are made to a job so the job notification plugin should be helpful.  This plugin adds a subsection to each Jenkins job for us to configure.  We have to check the checkbox and enter email addresses for each job to notify us whenever there's a change.

I want to define some environment variable that contains emails so I don't have to go into each job to add/delete email addresses for interested parties; that I can just add/delete addresses from this variable.  Can someone tell me how to do this or am I out of luck and the field only takes email addresses and not variables containing email addresses.

Screenshots from my Jenkins:

Global variables defined in Jenkins: [image]

Field in Jenkins job notification heading that doesn't allow me to enter a variable for emails: [image]

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be fixed in version 2.144 (both "${DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS}" and "$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS" reference the global property fine in the "Recipients" field).

Otherwise, I use the [Email Extension Plugin ("Email-ext")](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for much more flexibility.

Once installed, to configure the plugin, navigate to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, and scroll down to "Extended E-mail Notification".

- There you can set the global defaults, such as "Default Recipients".
- These settings are assigned to tokens, such as "$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS".
- Click the "?" button for each setting and note the token name.
- Note the "cc:" and "bcc:" prefixes to put an address on "cc" or "bcc").

Then, in your job configuration (/job/myJobName/configure):

1. Go to "Post-build Actions"
2. Click "Add post-build action" and select "Editable Email Notification".
3. Ensure that "$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS" is in the "Project Recipient List", with any other addresses (note the "cc:" prefix to put addresses on "cc").

Click on the "Advanced settings" (bottom left of the "Editable Email Notification" configuration) to show the "Triggers" section and configure emails depending on the build status, like "Always", "Failure", etc...). Click the "Advanced" button for each trigger to get more options.

Once this setup is done, you can edit the global "$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS" to change the emailing for all jobs configured as above, and have the functionality you require.

PS: I know this is old, I hope my answer may help others - like me - that have the same question.

Comment: can you create different groups of emails for different sets of jobs and set to these via pipeline code? i was thinking maybe Roles Bases Authorization Strategy could do this..but not sure how to reference those roles/groups via code

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to follow a similar approach as that of yours, with the only difference of having a job parameter being assigned the recipient's address.

I encountered a problem where the plugin wasn't able to parse the job/environment variable to it's assigned value (the email address).

For example,

```
emailID=xxxxxx@yyyyy.com
```

Now this particular variable was being sent into the emailing list as **${emailID}** and **not** as **xxxxxxx@yyyyyy.com**

The fix? Really funny.

Your variable **must be the first comma seperated value** in the mailing list.
You can refer to the attached image below.

[As you can see, just keep the variable first, and then your predefined values or the plugin's variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2BJ.png)